C# & ASP.NET Core: POSTing to a one-many relationship?
Context: I'm making a React + C# ASP.NET Core Web API.
Essentially, I have a one-to-many relationship between a Food object and a Review object.
public class Review
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    // ... [other properties] ...

    public int FoodId { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public virtual Food? Food { get; set; }
}

public class Food
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    // ... [other properties] ...

    [ForeignKey("FoodId")]
    public List<Review> Ratings { get; set; } = [];
}

POSTing to Food works fine, but for Review, I want to send the following JSON to an endpoint:
{
    // ... [other properties] ...
    foodId: [foodId]
}

And have the controller create a Review object so I can GET a list of all reviews with a reference to their food to use in the frontend,.
I also want the Food object's list of Reviews to be updated, so when I GET a Food, a list of all of its reviews is returned as well.
Here's my mapping:
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Food>()
        .HasMany(f => f.Ratings)
        .WithOne(r => r.Food)
        .HasForeignKey(r => r.FoodId);
}

public DbSet<Food> Foods { get; set; } = null!;
public DbSet<Review> Reviews { get; set; } = null!;

Currently, I post by sending the following JSON:
{
    ... [other properties] ...
    foodId: 1
}

and in the controller, I have an endpoint to make a review:
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Review>> PostReview(Review review)
{
    var foodToReview = await _context.Foods.FindAsync(review.FoodId);

    if (foodToReview == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    
    _context.Reviews.Add(review);

    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

    return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetReview), new { id = review.Id }, review);
}

But it doesn't actually add the created Review to the Food object because when I call GET on the Food of whatever id I added the Review to, the list of reviews is empty still.
Also, to be able to POST to the ASP.NET Core Web API, I have to make the Food reference in Review nullable, which I don't see anyone else do, and I'm wondering what the best practice for that is.

Your POST is fine. When using the GET on Food, you need to add .Include(f => f.Reviews) to ensure that Reviews are fetched and sent with the Food. As a general rule I don't recommend sending Entities to views as in more realistic data models the view doesn't need to know everything about the entity and it leads to bad assumptions that those same entity references can be sent back to the controller. They don't. What goes back are plain JSON data that gets reconstituted into new, typically incomplete entity instances.

@StevePy Thank you, that worked! In regards to the second part, should I instead have a new class type for what the PostReview method returns, and have that class be of only the essential parts of the comment model?

Not exactly. Think of the entity as the data model, representing what is stored in the DB. A ViewModel class is a representation that only worries about what the view needs. That might be a subset of properties from an entity, flattened information from related data, etc. When you do something like adding a product to an order, instead of sending some detached Product entity with a quantity, all you need to send is a ProductID and quantity. Attempting to reference the passed "product" entity wouldn't work as you expect since the DbContext won't be tracking it.
